# Iterating/update inside for loop

Tags: apex, email, case

UPDATE:
If I have more then one field then what is the best way of doing, currently I'm doing the way it showed in the answer:

```
c.case_dispatch_date__c = csIdToEmailMessageMap.get(c.id).MessageDate;
c.rec_date__c = c = csIdToEmailMessageMap.get(c.id).MessageDate;
```

I do not like the fact that every time I have to have this line of code `csIdToEmailMessageMap.get(c.id).<field>;`

END

```
 for(EmailMessage eMsg : Trigger.new) 
 {  
   List<Case> caseList = [SELECT id FROM Case WHERE Id = :eMsg.ParentId ];
   if (caseList.size()>0)  {
     for(Case c : caseList){ 
       c.case_dispatch_date__c = eMsg.MessageDate;
       update c;
     }
    }
 }
```

I am trying to update the `case dispatch date` based on the email sent and I know that I should not be writing `update` inside the loop, how can I optimized?

Comment: Considering you already have accepted an answer, if you need additional assistance it may be less confusing to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  map<ID,EmailMessage> csIdToEmailMessageMap = new map<ID,EmailMessage>();
  for(EmailMessage eMsg : Trigger.new) 
      csIdToEmailMessageMap.put(eMsg.parentId,eMsg); // get parentIds

  List<Case> caseList = [SELECT id FROM Case WHERE Id IN :csIdToEmailMessageMap.keySet() ];
  for(Case c : caseList) 
      c.case_dispatch_date__c = csIdToEmailMessageMap.get(c.id).MessageDate;
  update caseList;
```

Above assumes that if two EmailMessage arrives in same batch with the same Case parent, only one will set the `case_dispatch_date__c`. Which wins is indeterminate but since if in the same batch, it doesn't matter as the `MessageDate` will be the same day.

Comment: It's a stylistic difference of opinion, but I think in this case, it would be good to include scope brackets `{ }` around the logic of those two `for` loop bodies to clearly demonstrate what is part of the loop and what is not.

Comment: you are trying to access `case_dispatch_date__c` without querying

Comment: @MarkPond, I indented a bit more but my personal style is to not use {..} in order to reduce the vertical length of answers. It mirrors the way I code. I know others may claim heresy on this. It is somewhat also a reaction to overly bloated OPs with blank lines, lines containing only `{` that make the posts so hard to read

Comment: @Ratan - not an issue, I'm setting the value, not referencing its value

Comment: Can you set the value of a field that you didn't query for? I could have sworn that syntax like this `c.case_dispatch_date__c = value` on a query result sObject would throw an exception or otherwise complain that the field didn't exist. Could have been a limitation from an old API version or mis-remembering but I could have sworn that you had to query for all of the fields that you were going to set like this...

Comment: you scared me ...no works fine, I just verified in DC.

Comment: @crop1645: where is `csParentIdSet ` coming from? in your SOQL

Comment: @NickKahn - Yikes, left over from a previous version; fixed. Thanks

Comment: Thanks... which approach is the best? out of both answers... rather best practice and advantages.

Comment: @NickKahn -- Both are equivalent, I've solved this problem sfdcweb's way too in other use cases; If anything, if you have more complex logic, having maps (sfdcweb's solution) rather than lists gives you more flexibility for later processing as they can be accessed via a map key. That said, I'd go with a solution that you feel is most understandable to you when you come back to look at the code in 6 months :-)

Comment: I have updated my question, I have one thought please see my question.

Comment: In a not well-known Apex trick, you can do the following: `c.case_dispatch_date__c = c.rec_date__c = csIdToEmailMessageMap.get(c.id).MessageDate;`

Answer (score 4):

first you can collect all the ParentId in set and query case based on set

And store query  result in map for further process

Next for loop you can use update `case_dispatch_date__c` value and perform DML on map values

```
set<Id> setMessage = new set<Id> ();
for(EmailMessage eMsg : Trigger.new) 
{
  setMessage.add(eMsg.ParentId);
}
map<Id, Case> mapCase = new map<Id, Case>([SELECT id FROM Case WHERE Id IN:setMessage ]);
for(EmailMessage eMsg : Trigger.new) 
{  
   if (mapCase.containskey(eMsg.ParentId))  {
       mapCase.get(eMsg.ParentId).case_dispatch_date__c = eMsg.MessageDate;
    }
 }
 update mapCase.values();
```

Comment: Ratan -- you changed your moniker?  Cool

Comment: @cropredy Thankas. yes i thought it will look good so changed. :-)

Comment: 1+ it was very hard to pick the best answer :-)

Comment: @NickKahn No problem. glad you solved your problem :-)